# Requesting help with Armstrong Topology Section 8.2 Problem 2

Tags: algebraic-topology, simplicial-complex

I'm working on Topology by Armstrong, and I'm struggling to complete problem 2 in section 8.2.

The problem statement is as follows:

> Show the elementary 1-cycles, mentioned in Section 8.1, generate $Z_1(K)$ for any complex $K$.

In section 8.1, an elementary 1 cycle is defined as follows:

> An oriented, simple closed polygonal curve in K, when thought of as the sum of its oriented edges...may be referred to as an elementary 1-cycle.

My approach was essentially to do the following:

1] show that cycles are precisely those 1-chains where each vertex appears the same number of times as the initial and as the final element of an edge

2] show that if a chain has that property, it's generated by an elementary 1 cycle

My proof of 1]:

Suppose $s = \sum_{i} \lambda_i(v_i, u_i) \in Z_1(K)$, that is, $\sum_{i} \lambda_i \partial (v_i, u_i) = 0$. Then $\sum_{i} \lambda_i(u_i - v_i) = 0$ so $\sum_i \lambda_i u_i = \sum_i \lambda_i v_i$. Reduce the sums on both sides so that each distinct vertex appears only once. Then we have $\sum_k \alpha_k u_k = \sum_k \beta_k v_k$. In particular, note that because we consider formal combinations of distinct vertices, by definition this equality holds if and only if for every vertex it appears (weighted by the $\lambda_i$) an equal number of times as the final and as the initial vertex of an edge.

My proof of 2] (this is where I got stuck):

We proceed by induction on the number of terms in the reduced sum form of $s$, say $t$. Note that we don't need to consider $t = 1$ or $t = 2$; such linear combinations will not be cycles. [some work omitted - here I just explained why combinations of 1 and 2 edges aren't cycles]. For the base case, we consider $t = 3$; [I'm also relatively confident in my proof for t = 3, so I'm omitting it for brevity].

For the induction step, my idea was essentially to let $c$ be a maximal subsum of $s$ that is still generated by elementary 1 cycles [maximal in the number of terms in the sum]. Then I thought I could show $s-c$ has less terms than $s$, and apply the induction hypothesis. Here, I got stuck, because I couldn't figure out how to show that $s-c$ has less terms than $s$.

I'm aware this is VERY likely not the simplest way to tackle this problem but I figured I'd give my full thought process anyway. If anyone has any simpler ideas or preferably a way to salvage my own proof, they'd be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: (2) seems false to me. When you say "generated by an elementary 1-cycle", you mean any cycle has the form $ne$, where $n$ is an integer and $e$ is an elementary cycle? But a cycle could look like $0 \to 1 \to 2 \to 0 \to 3 \to 4 \to 0$, which doesn't have that property.

Comment: @HewWolff Good comment; I should've been more clear.  By generated I mean that it is a linear combination, not just a scalar multiple, of elementary one cycles. Your example is a linear combination of the cycles (0, 1) + (1, 2) + (2, 0) and (0, 3) + (3, 4) + (4, 0).

Comment: @HewWolff I realized I may have misunderstood your question - but in fact the cycle you list does have the desired property, because at least the way we write cycles in Armstrong means that your example actually does have that property. Your example would be written as (0, 1) + (1, 2) + (2, 0) + (0, 3) + (3, 4) + (4, 0). Note that 0 appears twice as the initial vertex and twice as the final vertex, 1, 2, 3, and 4 all appear once as both.

Comment: I was thinking that a cycle which revisits a vertex is not simple, but I would have to check the definition in the book.

Comment: @HewWolff I think you're right, that your given cycle is not simple, but it is generated by two elementary/simple cycles (it is a sum of simple cycles).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after talking with some people I came to a solution that is very similar in spirit to what I'm trying to do, but works a little better.

We can WLOG assume the coefficients of $s$ are positive; for any negative coefficient, we can swap the order of the 1 simplex and omit it from the sum. Now instead of doing induction on the number of terms, we proceed by induction on the total number of edges (more precisely, the sum of coefficients of s).

The base cases are essentially the same, so I'll omit them here.

For the induction hypothesis, the idea is similar, but we don't care about taking a maximal term generated by one cycles. Rather, we build an elementary one cycle explicitly, subtract it from $s$, and apply the induction hypothesis. To build an elementary one cycle explicitly, start with some edge $(v_0, v_1)$. Because $v_1$ appears an equal number of times as an initial vertex, there is some $v_2$ such that $(v_1, v_2)$ is an edge in $s$. Because $s$ is written in reduced form, we can assume $v_2 \neq v_0$. Continue this process, building a sequence of vertices $v_0, ..., v_k$ such that $v_i \neq v_j$ if $i \neq j$ and $(v_i, v_{i+1})$ gives a distinct edge of $s$ for all $i$.

Because $s$ has finitely many edges, eventually the only edge who's initial vertex is $v_k$ will be $(v_k, v_i)$ where $v_i$ is already on the list and $i < k$. Then $c = (v_i, v_{i+1}) + (v_{i+1}, v_{i+2}) + ... + (v_{k}, v_i)$ is an elementary 1 cycle contained in $s$.

Now $c$ has the desired property [every vertex in $c$ appears an equal number of times as the final and as the initial vertex] and so does $s$, and therefore so does $s-c$. But $s-c$, when reduced, contains strictly fewer edges. Thus, by the induction hypothesis, $s-c$ is generated by elementary 1 cycles. Because $c$ is itself an elementary 1 cycle, it follows $s = s-c+c$ is generated by elementary 1 cycles.

Comment: This idea seems sound. But I'm confused about the step where we make the coefficients positive: when you flip a 1-simplex (replacing $(a_0, a_1)$ with $-(a_1, a_0)$), couldn't you lose the "each vertex appears the same number of times" property? I think you don't need to do this anyway, and can just do the induction on $\Sigma |\lambda_i|$ for the 1-chain $\Sigma \lambda_i s_i$.

Comment: Hmm, that’s a good point. 

I don’t think it’s actually a problem, because I think the way I would say it is that we can WLOG consider all chains to have positive coefficients, and after we’ve already made that simplification we then compute the boundary; we will get that some subset of these chains both have positive coefficients and boundary 0, which preserves the final = initial property.

The reason I wanted to make the coefficients positive is to ensure that “number of edges” is well defined, but I suppose you could also make it sum of abs of the coefficients without flipping edges

Comment: I still don't understand "we can WLOG consider all chains to have positive coefficients". Given a 1-cycle $c$, you can certainly flip 1-simplexes to get another 1-cycle $c'$ whose coefficients are all positive, and then you can show that $c'$ is a combination of elementary 1-cycles as required. How do you then show that the original $c$ has this property?

Comment: There are two justifications. First, it's an order issue. We can consider every CHAIN to have positive coefficients, not just every cycle. After that, we consider cycles, and then because they go to zero, they have the # final = # initial property,  but because we started with positive coefficient chains they also have positive coefficients. The second way to see this is if an edge has a negative weight, its vertices contribute against their respective tallies in # final and # initial. Swapping it does swap which they count for, but also swaps their signs/how they count, so it cancels out.